# Wait until gobalEval has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to execute a callback after the following has finished:

```
jQuery.globalEval(myUnknownContent);
```

However, `myUnknownContent` might have some Ajax calls in it. So far, I'm using a timeout of 100ms, but this is not an elegant and reliable solution.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ajaxSend](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) and [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) for that:

```
var onCompletion = function(){
    // put here the stuff you want done after all unknown content
}
var ajaxSent = false;
jQuery(document).ajaxSend(function(){ ajaxSent = true });
jQuery.globalEval(myUnknownContent);
if (ajaxSent) {
    jQuery(document).ajaxStop(onCompletion);
} else {
    onCompletion(); // use setTimeout(onCompletion,0) if you want it asynchronous
}
```

Comment: Note for OP: With the above, `onCompletion` will be called synchronously if there were no ajax calls, asynchronously if there were.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Do you think it might be a problem ?

Comment: Totally depends on the OP's use case. If it were going to be a *general* function (like a promise's `then`), I'd say it was, definitely, because it makes for a chaotic result (in fact, this is one of the flaws with jQuery's promises stuff; fortunately, ES6 gets it right in this respect). But if it's not a general function, but just code doing this in one place, then it could not matter.

Comment: @Girish it waits for all pending ajax requests to be finished